# programmatically interact with webpage

Tags: asp.net, python, automation, python-3.x, html

http://www.apsalin.com/convert-cartesian-to-geodetic.aspx

I would like to write out a python program that opens the above webpage, fills out 3 text boxes with specific values, hits the "convert" button, and extracts the answer. What is the best way to accomplish this? I've heard of mechanize but that's not available for Python 3.

If there's nothing available to do this in python, what would be a good alternative way of automating website interaction? I'm open to any type of program or programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). It should have everything you need to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Is Python 3 a pre-requisite? If not, you can check out [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). 
Described as a **browser automation tool** which is primarily used for automated testing. There are [Python bindings availble](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium). I currently use these.